# Trying to find string vectors that don't match

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to C++. I have four 2D vectors of strings: orders, refunds, matchup, and nomatch.  I am looking for refunds that appear in orders (checking order number and item).  When they match I put the two entries together into the matchup vector.  I then want to put any refunds that don't match into the nomatch vector.  The closest that I've gotten is this code.  The matchup vector works, but the nomatch vector ends up having the same refunds that match and were added to my matchup vector.  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks--

Al

```
for (i = 0; i < refundVector.size(); ++i)
{
    // Check for matching orders
    for (a = 0; a < orderVector.size(); ++a)
    {
        if (refundVector[i][0] == orderVector[a][0])
        {
            if (refundVector[i][3] == orderVector[a][3])
            {
                matchupVector.push_back(refundVector[i]);
                matchupVector.push_back(orderVector[a]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Check for refunds not found
    for (a = 0; a < orderVector.size(); ++a)
    {
        if (!(std::find(orderVector[a].begin(), orderVector[a].end(), refundVector[i][0]) == orderVector[a].end()))
        { 
            nomatchVector.push_back(refundVector[i]);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are algorithm functions such as `std::set_intersection` and `std::set_difference` that would work much more efficiently than writing hand-coded `for` loops.  You should post what exactly the type is that stored in these vectors.

Comment: Sorry.  All four vectors contain vectors of strings and are declared:  vector< vector<string> > orderVector; 
 vector< vector<string> > refundVector; 
 vector< vector<string> > matchupVector;
 vector< vector<string> > nomatchVector;

Comment: You could have used a simple struct `{ std::string order_number; std::string order_id; }` and have an array of those instead of having storing these individual items in element `[0]` and `[3]`?  If you did that, then this becomes much simpler, and wouldn't require a double nested loop.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of doing vectors of structs, but it was inherited code, and I would have to change the logic everywhere else :-(...  It may come to that since I can't seem to crack this logic.  I guess I could copy everything into structs for just this, but yuck...

Comment: What you could have done is to use named constants instead of magic numbers like `0` and `3`.

Comment: Also [please look at this code](http://ideone.com/huk0K8).  Are the final results what you're trying to accomplish?  If it is, it is basically a 2 line function using `set_intersection` to find the common elements, and `set_symmetric_difference` to find the uncommon elements in both arrays.  Note the comparater to compare items 0 and 3, since a sorting criteria is required for the `std::set...` functions to work properly.

Comment: I'm looking it over.  Thanks.  It may do the trick, but the entries in the orderVector don't have the same number of fields as the entries in the refundVector; so there would never be an exact one to one match (hence comparing individual fields).